# Can i open a menu with a clock of a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently making a js game in class and one of the criteria is to make a menu on one of the buttons on my keyboard. I'm trying to restart my game with spacebar but I'm completely clueless. I've tried the following:

```
        var start = restart();
    
        if (keyboard.space) {
             Program.restart();
        };
```

But it keeps telling me that 'restart' isn't defiened. My first thought is to do something like "def(restart)" but i'm clueless. How should i continue?

Comment: It looks like we can't help you. You've to learn JS first, SO is not a tutorial library.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, you seem to be in need of a [full tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) of JavaScript and web developement.

Comment: This was a question and I'm not in need of a tutorial. I think my teacher will give me a tutorial if we need one and I just want to know how to do this since I know it can be done with a small amount of code.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service either. Considering you'd need to get familiar with [common control flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks), [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions), [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) and specifically [Keyboard events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent), I'd say you'd need tutorials, or ask your teacher to actually teach you.